# Camera rendering not what is in view

Tags: 3d-view

i'm trying to render out different angles on this planet but when i move the camera and render the scene the objects are in  different locations relative to where they are in the viewport. Has anyone had this issue before or know how to solve it?

This is the viewport
[image]

and this is the render result 
[image]

This is the viewport
[image]

and this is the render result
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Viewport orientation is not the same thing as camera orientation. When you render, your viewport orientation is always ignored in favor of your camera orientation. Also, while you can have more than one camera in a scene, only one can be "active" at any time, and only the "active" one renders.  "Active" is not the same thing as "selected," since you can select a camera without activating it. If you look at the camera itself, from within the 3D View, you will see a small triangle on its front side, revealing its "Up" vector. This will be filled in black if the camera happens to be active, and not filled in at all if it is not active. This becomes a quick, visual way to know. If you look in the Outliner window for any camera, and uncollapse its children nodes, and click on the item indicated by the green camera icon, which appears directly beneath the original version you first clicked on, this will activate that camera. Once activated, hit Ctrl-Numpad0, and your viewport orientation will switch to that of this newly activated camera. If you render now, you will see a rendered shot consistent with that of your current view. Though it won't be exactly identical in any case, and I understand that this is normal behavior.